# Node JS Datastore read operation taking too long to return the data with Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-functions

I have two cloud function, the first cloud function is triggered by pubsub message and the second cloud function triggered by HTTP which insert the entries in the datastore. A cron that runs every one minute publishes a message to the pubsub queue which invokes the first cloud function. The main purpose of the first cloud function is to fetch all the entries from the datastore and process them. The problem is, the read operation to fetch entries from the datastore, it takes a too long time to run the query(fetch around 20k entries). Sometimes it seems like the cloud function has got aborted in between.

Due to datastore read/write per sec limit I am using shards but even then it's taking forever to return value from datastore.

Here is method related to read query -

```
async function fetchEntry(entityName, pageCursor) {
    let query = datastore.createQuery([entityName]).limit(2000);
    if (pageCursor) {
        query = query.start(pageCursor);
    }
    //console.log("Result jsonStr - " + JSON.stringify(results));
    const results = await datastore.runQuery(query);
    const entries = results[0];
    const info = results[1];
    if (info.moreResults !== Datastore.NO_MORE_RESULTS) {
        //console.log(`item in batch ${entityName} - ${entries.length}`);
        // If there are more results to retrieve, the end cursor is
        // automatically set on `info`. To get this value directly, access
        // the `endCursor` property.
        const results = await fetchEntry(hostName, entityName, info.endCursor);

        // Concatenate entities
        results[0] = entries.concat(results[0]);
        console.log(`${entityName} BATCH READ ${results[0].length}`);
        return results;
    }
    console.log(`${entityName} BATCH READ F - ${entries.length}`);
    return [entries, info];
}
```

I have read different blogs and tried different methods to overcome the same, here is my observation -

- Initially, I was not using pagination as I did not find any limitation on the maximum number of entities that can be fetched in a single read operation but to verify I added pagination, still it's taking the same time.
- If one cloud function is in progress and another message is published to queue the existing processing gets aborted and new processing takes over it. (Checked through stack driver logging). I stopped the cron so that a new cloud function invoke doesn't happen, it took around 5 min to process 4k entries.

Comment: FYI You can mark an entire block of code by using the {} button in the editor.  Just indenting the first line isn't really good enough.